# Virtual Class and Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I get a compile error "cannot convert 'Chips' to 'GroceryItem' and I'm having trouble figuring out how to actually convert something to a virtual class object.  Teacher provided a 'GroceryCart' class that adds GroceryItems to the cart in 'main' and prints the cart out.

```
class GroceryItem {
public:
    virtual ~GroceryItem();
    virtual float GetPrice() = 0;
    virtual char* GetDescription() = 0;
    virtual float GetWeight() = 0;
};



 #include "GroceryItem.h"

class Chips : public GroceryItem {
public:
    Chips();
    ~Chips();
    float GetPrice();
    char* GetDescription();
    float GetWeight();
private:
    float price;
    char* itemName;
    float weight;
};

#include "GroceryItem.h"
#include "Chips.h"

Chips::Chips() {
    price = 0.75;
    itemName = new char[5];
    itemName = "Chips";
    weight = 1.0;
}

Chips::~Chips() {
    delete this;
}

float Chips::GetPrice() {
    return price;
}

char* Chips::GetDescription() {
    return itemName;
}

float Chips::GetWeight() {
    return weight;
}



 int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    GroceryCart c;
    c.AddItemToCart(new Chips);
    std::cout << c;
    return 0;
}
void GroceryCart::AddItemToCart(GroceryItem *i)
{
    items.push_back(i);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the GroceryCart `AddItemToCart` method?

Comment: You should tag the language in the question.

Comment: What's the exact error message you get, and on what line?

Comment: it has to do with the AddItemToCart(new Chips), but it's nothing with the AddItemToCart method.  I think it's something with creating a copy of GroceryItem manually and assigning new Chips() to it in the Chips constructor, but I'm not exactly sure how it works

Comment: `delete this;` there is a time, and a place, where this is acceptable. It is not here.

Answer (score 0):

provide full error log, check that container parameterized with pointer to GroceryItem (<GroceryItem*>)

As someone pointed out

```
delete[] itemName; //destructor
```

but you also have to define non-trivial copy-constructor/operator=, so it's better to replace char* with std::string, also need defined destructor for base abstract class even it's pure virtual.